# How to launch android voice search from NFC

Tags: android, nfc

I have an NFC writer app installed to write to a tag, but the voice search app isn't listed in the list of apps to choose from. I have the option to launch an app from an app uri, but not sure if that's what I need. If it is, what is the uri that I must use?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using nfc task launcher, Make a new task and add an "open activity" action from the applications and shortcuts action menu.

Then select Google as the application and set 
`"Com.google.android.googlequicksearchboxVoiceSearchActivity"` 
as the activity.

Then save the task to an nfc tag and you're all set. If you want to take it further you can download home 2 switcher and set it up to run that task on a double home key press which is what I did. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

use nxp tag writer app, to write the desired app on your tag.

If the app is not listed on the list, you get to see. You can alternately write the app name along with the package name.

you can use this code to get the package name of any app, which is running in the foreground.

```
ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager)    
getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> RunningTask = mActivityManager
                .getRunningTasks(1);
        ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = RunningTask.get(0);

        String foregroundApp = ar.topActivity.getClassName().toString();
```

hope, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Voice search is not a separate app, it is just one `Activity` in the Google app. To start it, you need to launch the `SearchActivity` from the package `com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox`
with action `android.intent.action.SEARCH_LONG_PRESS`. This cannot be done directly from an NFC tag, because intents generated by an NFC tag have always a different action (for example `android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED`). So you will have to write your own app for this.

Comment: And it's not possible to use the `content://` protocol to do something like this? `content://com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/SearchActivity/SEARCH_LONG_PRESS`

Comment: I don't know... I may have completely misunderstood my reading of `content://`